# count specific name and date - just oldest ones

Tags: excel

is there some possibilities how count specific names with date and time?

for example, I have in pivot table

E90 (specific code) Jim (name) - 23.7.2015 6:00 (date and time), 
E90 (specific code) Tom (name) - 23.7.2015 7:00

A90 (specific code) John (name) - 24.7.2015 7:00
A90 (specific code) Jim (name) - 24.7.2015 8:00

A90 (specific code) John (name) - 25.7.2015 9:00
A90 (specific code) Tom (name) - 25.7.2015 10:00

I need do some "summary" where I will have names and count of names, but minus the name from latest time

for example

Jim 1
John 2

is there some option how to do it easy? (I have pivot table with about 150 rows)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pivot table, I assume you have access to the table the information is built off of?  You can get a list of the unique names, put those in a column, and then use `countIf()` to count how many times a name appears.  You can use `countifs()` to use multiple criteria, which could include a rule NOT to count if the name is from the most recent date.

[image]

So, you can use `=countifs([name range],[cell with a name, for reference],[date range],"<>[most recent date]")`

Let me know if that's not quite it, or if you have any other questions.  I am pretty sure, if you don't have access to the table's data, you can use this same formula on the pivot table, just be aware as you collapse/expand sections, the calculation will change.

Comment: countif(s) is not working for me, because I have date and time and I need resolution by the time, something as count (or get "one point" to the name) minus last name by the time, for specific code (last name solve issue and he shouldnt get "point")

Comment: @Tereza - can you explain that a little more? I don't quite get what you mean. "I need resolution by the time...", what  do you mean by that?

Comment: https://img2.brain3.photobox.com/28930466de656687956172f383d862d4916ada7f23a2f261e0f65c8a4380237be3e5b43c.jpg - like this - who is first, by the time, get one point..